# Excel, Return Value for Most Recent Date txt

Tags: excel-formula

[image]

New to excel formula, is that a way I can update column D which only give me most recent date notes, for this case, it will be only return back 2020.01.10 and get rid of 2020.01.07.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(A2;SEARCH("????.";A2;13)+5)
```

Exchange semicolon with comma if your Excel version uses commas.

With this formula, make sure date always starts in this format:
2020.
2021.

You can not write date like this:
20.01.10

or

10.01.2020

[image]

Comment: what is your ???? mean?

Comment: if you changed the second line date from 2020.1.7 to 2020.01.14, is that a way to pull out current date, return me 2020.01.14 only.

Comment: This formula will return the first date entry in the cell only.
By the way: Excel doesn't handle it as date, but as string. It is not a real date in Excel.
If the newest date is not always at the top or at the bottom, it is not possible to extract that line with formulas.

Comment: =LEFT(A2,FIND(CHAR(10),A2)-1) I have researched a whole day and figure this out. It works fine for my situation. Hope, it can help someone else.